# An issue of database files write

Tags: cnosdb

In the flush task execution

`

```
 if ctx.wal_sender.send(task).await.is_ok() 
     && timeout(Duration::from_secs(3), rx).await.is_err() 
 { 
     info!("Flush: failed to receive clear wal files result in 3 seconds",); 
 }
```

}
`

2nd. Task to check the count of TSM-files to compact if they are too many. The files generated in this flush have not yet been recorded in the summary, so the check-to-compact sometimes may find nothing to compact. It will also not cause any bug, but still need comments to tell future developers why to put it here but not the persistence of the summary changes.